# Setting table layout in the Android

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout

I tried to make table layout like this in the Android.

First column - 2 buttons, next column one button in second row. The size of the buttons should be the same. I use 0 width and weight 1 and stretch the columns.

[image: Layout]

In the XML:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_stereo_system_state"
                style="@style/StyleButton"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_off"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_button_on_off"
                android:text="@string/button_text_option_off" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_stereo_system_radio"
                style="@style/StyleButton"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_off"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_button_play"
                android:text="@string/button_text_play_radio" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_stereo_system_cd"
                style="@style/StyleButton"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_off"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_button_play"
                android:text="@string/button_text_play_cd" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

In the style:

```
<style name="StyleButton">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">10dip</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_text_button</item>
</style>
```

With this source code in second row button is stretched and takes the whole row. How to make this?

Comment: Maybe to add invisible button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (as you speculate in your comment) is to add another button the same as the rest and set the visibility to invisible.  (See docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility)).

Basically simply add the following line to your XML:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```